# What is reason behind Christianity most popular religious as of now?

Tags: christian-living, comparative-christianity

I know its broad topic and debatable, but still If anyone can explain why Christianity most popular religious?

Comment: Your question, as currently asked, is far to broad and opinion-based for this site. This is a Q&A site rather than a discussion site, and questions must be objectively answerable rather than being discussion-starters. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) Meanwhile, I do hope you'll stick around and browse some of the other questions and answers here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Christian faith has always been popular. From its beginnings during the time of the apostles - about two thousand years ago - there have been three major factors that have contributed to its ever increasing relevance and growth. (i) It is God's plan for the salvation of mankind - and as such, the Christian faith was blessed with the presence of Christ on earth, with the evidence of his death and the indisputable proof of his resurrection (ii) Light shines brightest when the darkness is heaviest. In contrast to other religions, terror, racism, and other societal ills cannot find cover or support in the new testament Christian faith. While Christian orthodoxy is not without its own historical problems (the crusades, inquisitions, etc.) - when we return to Christ's words himself, we find that when Christianity is true to its creed and as Christians we abide by what Jesus said was the greatest command of all "love God with all your heart, and your neighbor as yourself - Mark 12:30-31." The acts of terror perpetrated in the name of God by other faiths, which they in turn claim are justified by their religious texts can never find support in the new testament Christian message that Christ proclaimed (iii) It is a simple faith to adhere to. Christianity does not specify a time to pray, or a way to pray. It does not require pilgrimages or acts of outwards piety. It emphasizes personal relationship with God. It is a liberating religion - one that inclines the individual to seek God for themselves - to study the scriptures without the filter of elders, priests and spiritual leaders. Most everyday people can identify with that. To seek God is to seek answers for a yearning within one's soul. Just as no two people can have the same DNA, so too is the spiritual quest of all men. Each man/woman seeks to know God in a unique way. Christianity's simple message of salvation from sin, redemption and restoration is one that everyday people can recognize and appreciate.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  Unfortunately, the question you've answered is not one that is good for our format, since it invites opinion-based answers.  As a result, it will likely soon be closed. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you're a new visitor, I'd like to recommend the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)